Unable to access a Drupal portal containerized in multipass VM (Docker Swarm) from host browser
I am new to Docker Swarm. I took below steps to start Postgres and Drupal container on swarm managed nodes created via multipass. However, I am not able to access the Drupal from my host machine (browser). I need some help to understand if this is possible and if so, then what am I missing?
Steps taken are as below :

Created Docker Swarm with 2 managers and 1 worker.

Created overlay network : docker network create --driver overlay overlay_custom

Created 2 services on this network : docker service create --name psql --network overlay_custom -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass postgres:14
and docker service create --name=drupal -p 80:80 drupal:9

ssh into the multipass VM node (manager2) which is running Drupal :



Tried to access the drupal site from host browser : http:\\10.199.127.84\ . This yielded site not reachable error:



I was able to access the Drupal site via curl http:\\10.199.127.84\ from any node in this swarm. It gave me a redirect page.
I referred to this post, but didn't address my issue : Accessing running container (inside VM) from host OS

If you want to downvote a post, at least leave a comment explaining the reasoning behind the downvote so the person can improve. idk why the downvote.
